# Access google assistant Built-in (Bll) app actions from diagflow or google cloud account?

Tags: android, app-actions, diagflow

I don't want to publish my app on play console.
If I signup for diagflow/Google cloud NLP, can I receive for example, the "Message" action from communication category of Bll AI assistant app actions?

I understand that in general people signs up in play console and tests apps to use AI assistant built-in app actions or create custom actions.

I want to do the same but using google cloud NLP. My android app will send audio/text data to google cloud and will receive action & intent like "message".
I will deep link the action in my app.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't publish your app on the Play store, then your users will not be able to trigger App Actions BIIs.  There is no workaround for this requirement.  It's currently required to upload to at least an internal test track in order to create a preview that lets you test App Actions using your own Google account on a device or emulator that you're signed in to.  That requirement might be relaxed for testing some day, but it's absolutely required for general use.